# How to add the sig. and make font size varies with the size of correlation coefficient using ggpairs

Tags: r, ggally

I'm troubled by the plot below. Would someone give me some suggestions on how to creat this kind of plot?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The package `psych` has a built-in function to do just that:

```
library(psych)
pairs.panels(iris)
```

[image]